# Python How to import modules from same level packages with __init__.py?

Tags: python-3.x, import, package, structure, project

I am having problems to organize the project structure and successfully run the program. I dont want to use the sys.path module, so I choose to create **init**.py files. But i notice redundancy and I am confused how to properly do this. Other packages need also modules of neighbored packages.

```
src
- __init__.py
- main.py
- data
-- __init__.py
-- data_loader.py
- util
-- __init__.py
-- stringUtil.py
```

_*init*_.py

```
import .data
import .util
```

main.py

```
from data import *
from utils import *

def __init__():
    print(StringUtil.substringRight("Hello world!", "l"))
    loader = DataLoader("C:/SOME/PATH/")
```

data/_*init*_.py

```
from .data import *
```

data/data_loader.py

```
from util.stringUtils import StringUtil

class DataLoader()
    def __init__(self, path):
        StringUtil.printHierarchyTree(path)
```

util/_*init*_.py

```
from .util import *
```

util/stringUtil

```
class StringUtil:
    @staticmethod
    def substringRight():
        ...
```

I just want to load all modules and classes upon start of the app.

It says:

```
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
StringUtil.substringRight
NameError: name 'StringUtil' is not defined
```

also the Data Loader doesnt know StringUtil class

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be in main.py instead of

```
from utils import *
```

this line?

```
from util import *
```

Anyway using

```
from some_package import *
```

is always bad practise, you should always import only specific things instead of using asterisk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yeah I made a typo but the problem is the same. I understand your point but where should I make all the imports? If I am correct, then the init.py should only contain all the classes in the modules of the same directory to load all when importing in main "from util import *" since init.py is called due to calling the "util" folder.

Comment: OK, so I tried to reproduce your problem and I have this solution. In the first case, you don't need __init__.py inside src folder, so you can remove it. Then inside `data\__init__.py` change import on this `from data.data_loader import DataLoader`, in `util\__init__.py` change import on this `from util.stringUtil import StringUtil`, and in `data_loader.py` on this `from util.stringUtil import StringUtil`. With these changes, I have no error with your code. For more information, I would recommend this article https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_py.html